# Multi-User application and Azure Storage?

Tags: security, azure-storage

We are building an app that allows users to upload their own files (ex. images) in Azure Storage.

We are using Azure Storage and plan to use containers to separate the content of each user.

I am a bit lost in the part about security. What would be the best way to secure the container of each user? For example, would each container have a different key?

And if I want to display the image, do I point it directly to the azure storage URL or do I need to have a middle API service that gets it from Azure Storage then returns it?

Answer (score 2):

You have a key per storage account, not per container. You basically have two options - each **requires a middleware**:

1: **Upload** the files **through you middleware**. The client will send the files to your middleware which knows the storage account credentials to store the file in the desired container.

2: **Direct upload** to Azure Storage. The second option is to directly upload the files to the storage account. Since you don't want to expose storage account credentials to your clients, you will need some kind of middleware that gives your app a temporary SAS Token that allows it to upload the requested file (known as [Valet Key pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/valet-key)). Further information: ([File upload in Cloud Applications: The Options](https://about-azure.com/2018/08/20/file-upload-in-cloud-applications-the-options/))

If you want to display the image, you can point it directly to the Azure Storage URL (if you want them to be public readable) or you can again return the URLs with temporary SAS Token for each authorized user....

Comment: Thanks Martin. Public option is not a route we want to go to as there are some security concerns. 

The middleware approach looks good. We can reuse our Web API we are using. For the display of the image, with this approach, the Web API will process each URL of the image and generate the SAS token for each then send it back? Is this a good approach?

Comment: I think you can also generate a readonly, temporary SAS token for the whole user container and sent that back - depending on how much image you are going to have...

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the best way I think is to [Authorize the storage with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad), assign the RBAC role for the different users at the container level. Then they will just be able to access their own container, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-portal#assign-a-built-in-rbac-role).

To let the user upload files from an app via Azure AD Auth, you could refer to this doc - [Authorize access to blobs and queues with Azure Active Directory from a client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json).

To display the image, just click the `...` of your image(blob) in the portal -> `Generate SAS` -> `Generate blob SAS token and URL` -> copy the `Blob SAS URL`, you could access it directly in the browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy. Unfortunately, provisioning AD for each user is not possible. Their login data is outside of Azure.

Comment: @Water Well, it is a pity. Otherwise it should be a good solution.